# Presenting a Node JS webapp without hosting

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, hosting

I am asking about a question directed towards displaying my computers IP address at a coding competition, I am not hosting the website online and to give a demo is it safe for me to type my home computers ip after I start serving the webapp before I leave my house. Sorry if this question is pretty stupid.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why don't you just host your Node app locally while giving your presentation ? This way only `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` will show up.

Comment: You can try something called "tunneling" https://ngrok.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it using **[ngrok](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started)** with just 4 easy steps.

1. Download ngrok 
   (https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started)
2. Unzip to install ($ unzip /path/to/ngrok.zip)
3. Connect your account ($ ./ngrok authtoken 7mNUENYZgvsZUNxQvLiYN_4id6544gqY1rMA5HjabQS)
4. Fire it up ($ ./ngrok http 80)

Read the [documentation](https://ngrok.com/docs) on how to use ngrok.

Comment: Still at work, typing this under desk. I'll get home around 6 or 7 pm UK time,  Ill let you know then.

Comment: Thanks so much, works perfectly, just change port 80 to 3000 for Node :)